# Action after modal close in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I want to have custom pop up message to confirm deleting operation. I write it already, but I have a problem about how to connect it to my app. I click the 'X' button next to the record, then the modal pop up I confirm in it that I am sure what I am doing and after that, record is deleted. How I can make my function to wait for information from modal

Comment: Hi @Michał Kruk, I think it would help people to answer your question more effectively if you could add some of your code to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parent-child communication via custom events:

```
// Main component
<template>
  <div>
    <your-modal-component @accept="deleteEntity"></your-modal-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    deleteEntity() {
      // your delete functionality
    },
  },
};
</script>

// modal component
<template>
  <div>
    your modal code here
    <button @click="$emit('accept')">Accept</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

When users clicks on the delete btn, you first have to show your modal. After that, you simply emit event in case of accept. In your main component, you listen to that event and fire your delete function afterwards.

For more info about parent-child communication in Vue see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).